# This code is not executing in the documentclass [journal]{IEEEtran}?

Tags: tables, threeparttable, xtable

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\hyphenation{Smart Grid}
\usepackage{subfloat}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color} %for colors
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hhline}%%%
\usepackage{float} %for fix the image position
%\usepackage[]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{amsmath} %% for case bracket
%\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{multirow} %  for devide row
\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage{subcaption} % forr subfigures
\usepackage{multicol}
%\usepackage{subfig}
%\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\pagenumbering{gobble} %%% for without page numbers
\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[classicReIm]{kpfonts}
% You can include more LaTeX packages here


\begin{document}

%\selectlanguage{english} %%% remove comment delimiter ('%') and select language if required
\begin{table}[h!]
  \centering
  \caption{Accuracy analysis in terms of MAPE (\%)}
  \label{tab:MAPE}
\begin{tabular}{p{0.2in}p{0.4in}p{0.3in}p{0.3in}p{0.4in}p{0.3in}p{0.3in}p{0.4in}p{0.3in}p{0.3in}p{0.4in}p{0.3in}p{0.3in}p{0.4in}p{0.3in}p{0.3in}} \hline
 & \multicolumn{15}{p{4.7in}}{\centering{Electric load forecast models}} \\ \hline
Day  & \multicolumn{3}{p{0.9in}}{FCRBM-ELF} & \multicolumn{3}{p{1.3in}}{MI-mEDE-ANN} & \multicolumn{3}{p{0.9in}}{AFC-STLF} & \multicolumn{3}{p{1.0in}}{Bi-level} & \multicolumn{3}{p{0.9in}}{FS-ANN} \\ \hline
 & MAPD & $\sigmaup$${}^{2}$ & R & MAPD & $\sigmaup$${}^{2}$ & R & MAPD & $\sigmaup$${}^{2}$ & R & MAPD & $\sigmaup$${}^{2}$ & R & MAPD & $\sigmaup$${}^{2}$ & R \\ \hline
1 & 1.12 & 1.13 & 0.70 & 2.20 & 1.55 & 0.50 & 2.30 & 1.60 & 0.52 & 2.60 & 1.75 & 0.442 & 3.30 & 1.90 & 0.44 \\
2 & 1.10 & 0.98 & 0.68 & 2.10 & 1.45 & 0.58 & 2.15 & 1.55 & 0.56 & 2.80 & 1.73 & 0.46 & 3.35 & 1.80 & 0.36 \\ 
3 & 1.09 & 1.10 & 0.71 & 2.50 & 1.30 & 0.51 & 2.10 & 1.48 & 0.53 & 2.75 & 1.65 & 0.43 & 3.20 & 1.83 & 0.33 \\ 
4 & 1.03 & 0.97 & 0.80 & 2.02 & 1.20 & 0.50 & 2.40 & 1.49 & 0.54 & 2.85 & 1.75 & 0.44 & 3.40 & 1.85 & 0.34 \\ 
5 & 1.50 & 1.09 & 0.65 & 2.10 & 1.15 & 0.55 & 2.25 & 1.37 & 0.55 & 2.87 & 1.65 & 0.45 & 3.15 & 1.78 & 0.35 \\ 
6 & 1.30 & 1.07 & 0.75 & 2.30 & 1.34 & 0.65 & 2.15 & 1.35 & 0.69 & 2.89 & 1.69 & 0.59 & 3.25 & 1.95 & 0.49 \\ 
7 & 1.24 & 1.04 & 0.69 & 2.11 & 1.55 & 0.60 & 2.10 & 1.60 & 0.65 & 2.75 & 1.68 & 0.44 & 3.67 & 1.80 & 034 \\ 
8 & 1.23 & 1.02 & 0.70 & 2.15 & 1.45 & 0.50 & 2.09 & 1.65 & 0.55 & 2.70 & 1.77 & 0.55 & 3.55 & 1.83 & 0.45 \\ 
9 & 1.08 & 1.05 & 0.80 & 2.35 & 1.36 & 0.55 & 2.50 & 1.66 & 0.56 & 2.65 & 1.71 & 0.56 & 3.45 & 1.79 & 0.46 \\ 
10 & 1.05 & 0.99 & 0.79 & 2.40 & 1.39 & 0.69 & 2.44 & 1.67 & 0.60 & 2.63 & 1.78 & 0.65 & 3.10 & 1.87 & 0.55 \\ 
11 & 1.15 & 1.10 & 0.87 & 2.01 & 1.45 & 0.77 & 2.35 & 1.55 & 0.75 & 2.70 & 1.65 & 0.35 & 3.15 & 1.85 & 0.45 \\ 
12 & 1.25 & 1.11 & 0.65 & 2.06 & 1.50 & 0.55 & 2.12 & 1.58 & 0.55 & 2.60 & 1.66 & 0.45 & 3.59 & 1.77 & 0.35 \\ 
13 & 1.10 & 0.96 & 0.81 & 2.10 & 1.55 & 0.71 & 2.20 & 1.43 & 0.75 & 2.63 & 1.69 & 0.25 & 3.33 & 1.69 & 0.35 \\ 
14 & 1.12 & 0.99 & 0.79 & 2.12 & 1.37 & 0.75 & 2.23 & 1.47 & 0.70 & 2.36 & 1.75 & 0.40 & 3.39 & 1.59 & 0.30 \\ 
15 & 1.10 & 1.03 & 0.78 & 2.13 & 1.46 & 0.78 & 2.27 & 1.30 & 0.73 & 2.50 & 1.59 & 0.43 & 3.54 & 1.89 & 0.53 \\ 
16 & 1.18 & 1.05 & 0.79 & 2.00 & 1.39 & 0.70 & 2.13 & 1.35 & 0.78 & 2.58 & 1.67 & 0.58 & 3.23 & 1.88 & 0.48 \\ 
17 & 1.19 & 1.08 & 0.80 & 2.13 & 1.48 & 0.60 & 2.35 & 1.55 & 0.65 & 2.56 & 1.70 & 0.55 & 3.28 & 1.79 & 0.5 \\ 
18 & 1.21 & 1.09 & 0.85 & 2.19 & 1.29 & 0.85 & 2.10 & 1.36 & 0.64 & 2.65 & 1.72 & 0.54 & 3.92 & 1.85 & 0.44 \\ 
19 & 1.25 & 1.12 & 0.90 & 2.16 & 1.36 & 0.50 & 2.14 & 1.55 & 0.59 & 2.54 & 1.58 & 0.59 & 3.53 & 1.75 & 0.44 \\ 
20 & 1.44 & 0.95 & 0.67 & 2.17 & 1.47 & 0.60 & 2.15 & 1.45 & 0.48 & 2.50 & 1.65 & 0.58 & 3.22 & 1.69 & 0.48 \\ 
21 & 1.39 & 0.90 & 0.71 & 2.34 & 1.51 & 0.58 & 2.19 & 1.54 & 0.58 & 2.59 & 1.72 & 0.48 & 3.27 & 1.88 & 0.38 \\ 
22 & 1.17 & 0.99 & 0.75 & 2.10 & 1.50 & 0.75 & 2.10 & 1.40 & 0.59 & 2.80 & 1.63 & 0.49 & 3.60 & 1.80 & 0.39 \\ 
23 & 1.15 & 1.01 & 0.86 & 2.30 & 1.45 & 0.64 & 2.13 & 1.34 & 0.39 & 2.75 & 1.65 & 0.59 & 3.23 & 1.71 & 0.49 \\
24 & 1.08 & 1.07 & 0.87 & 2.01 & 1.34 & 0.73 & 2.24 & 1.60 & 0.58 & 2.65 & 1.53 & 0.48 & 3.89 & 1.74 & 0.38 \\ 
26 & 1.05 & 1.05 & 0.90 & 2.00 & 1.56 & 0.09 & 2.26 & 1.61 & 0.49 & 2.85 & 1.59 & 0.59 & 3.65 & 1.63 & 0.49 \\ 
27 & 1.03 & 1.10 & 0.88 & 2.10 & 1.40 & 0.58 & 2.10 & 1.48 & 0.77 & 2.55 & 1.68 & 0.57 & 3.83 & 1.80 & 0.47 \\ 
28 & 1.25 & 1.11 & 0.76 & 2.09 & 1.35 & 0.56 & 2.15 & 1.50 & 0.58 & 2.60 & 1.75 & 0.48 & 3.35 & 1.79 & 0.38 \\ \hline
Average& 1.12 & 2.23& 2.00& 2.50 & 3.4\\ \hline
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
```

Gives error like:

[image]

Comment: I just have one off-topic question (I'm too curious, sorry). Did you make this huge table yourself or use some generator? It is a great effort to add these numbers to such a big table :)

Comment: You didn't add a unit to the numbers. For example, you have to use `p{4.7cm}` or 
`p{4.7\textwidth}` instead of `p{4.7}`.

Comment: I have used but still not works

Comment: Would you be so kind to provide a minimal but complete example: that is to say, your table with the class declaration, the preamble, and so on.

Comment: Yes, wait provide you.

Comment: @GhulamHafeez I can compile your document without error. The only issue is that your table is too wide.

Comment: You generate table with same document classs, which i have mentioned@JouleV

Answer (score 2):

You should let TeX do the computations. In the example below I removed all the unnecessary packages. See at the bottom for advice.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[classicReIm]{kpfonts}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}


\begin{document}

%\selectlanguage{english} %%% remove comment delimiter ('%') and select language if required
\begin{table*}
\centering

\caption{Accuracy analysis in terms of MAPE (\%)}
\label{tab:MAPE}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  S[table-format=2.0]
  *{15}{S[table-format=1.2]}
  @{}
}
\toprule
 & \multicolumn{15}{c}{Electric load forecast models} \\
\cmidrule{2-16}
{Day} &
  \multicolumn{3}{c}{FCRBM-ELF} &
  \multicolumn{3}{c}{MI-mEDE-ANN} &
  \multicolumn{3}{c}{AFC-STLF} &
  \multicolumn{3}{c}{Bi-level} &
  \multicolumn{3}{c}{FS-ANN} \\
\cmidrule{1-4}\cmidrule{5-7}\cmidrule{8-10}\cmidrule{11-13}\cmidrule{14-16}
 & {MAPD} & {$\sigmaup^{2}$} & {R}
 & {MAPD} & {$\sigmaup^{2}$} & {R}
 & {MAPD} & {$\sigmaup^{2}$} & {R}
 & {MAPD} & {$\sigmaup^{2}$} & {R}
 & {MAPD} & {$\sigmaup^{2}$} & {R} \\
\midrule
1 & 1.12 & 1.13 & 0.70 & 2.20 & 1.55 & 0.50 & 2.30 & 1.60 & 0.52 & 2.60 & 1.75 & 0.44 & 3.30 & 1.90 & 0.44 \\
2 & 1.10 & 0.98 & 0.68 & 2.10 & 1.45 & 0.58 & 2.15 & 1.55 & 0.56 & 2.80 & 1.73 & 0.46 & 3.35 & 1.80 & 0.36 \\ 
3 & 1.09 & 1.10 & 0.71 & 2.50 & 1.30 & 0.51 & 2.10 & 1.48 & 0.53 & 2.75 & 1.65 & 0.43 & 3.20 & 1.83 & 0.33 \\ 
4 & 1.03 & 0.97 & 0.80 & 2.02 & 1.20 & 0.50 & 2.40 & 1.49 & 0.54 & 2.85 & 1.75 & 0.44 & 3.40 & 1.85 & 0.34 \\ 
5 & 1.50 & 1.09 & 0.65 & 2.10 & 1.15 & 0.55 & 2.25 & 1.37 & 0.55 & 2.87 & 1.65 & 0.45 & 3.15 & 1.78 & 0.35 \\ 
6 & 1.30 & 1.07 & 0.75 & 2.30 & 1.34 & 0.65 & 2.15 & 1.35 & 0.69 & 2.89 & 1.69 & 0.59 & 3.25 & 1.95 & 0.49 \\ 
7 & 1.24 & 1.04 & 0.69 & 2.11 & 1.55 & 0.60 & 2.10 & 1.60 & 0.65 & 2.75 & 1.68 & 0.44 & 3.67 & 1.80 & 0.34 \\ 
8 & 1.23 & 1.02 & 0.70 & 2.15 & 1.45 & 0.50 & 2.09 & 1.65 & 0.55 & 2.70 & 1.77 & 0.55 & 3.55 & 1.83 & 0.45 \\ 
9 & 1.08 & 1.05 & 0.80 & 2.35 & 1.36 & 0.55 & 2.50 & 1.66 & 0.56 & 2.65 & 1.71 & 0.56 & 3.45 & 1.79 & 0.46 \\ 
10 & 1.05 & 0.99 & 0.79 & 2.40 & 1.39 & 0.69 & 2.44 & 1.67 & 0.60 & 2.63 & 1.78 & 0.65 & 3.10 & 1.87 & 0.55 \\ 
11 & 1.15 & 1.10 & 0.87 & 2.01 & 1.45 & 0.77 & 2.35 & 1.55 & 0.75 & 2.70 & 1.65 & 0.35 & 3.15 & 1.85 & 0.45 \\ 
12 & 1.25 & 1.11 & 0.65 & 2.06 & 1.50 & 0.55 & 2.12 & 1.58 & 0.55 & 2.60 & 1.66 & 0.45 & 3.59 & 1.77 & 0.35 \\ 
13 & 1.10 & 0.96 & 0.81 & 2.10 & 1.55 & 0.71 & 2.20 & 1.43 & 0.75 & 2.63 & 1.69 & 0.25 & 3.33 & 1.69 & 0.35 \\ 
14 & 1.12 & 0.99 & 0.79 & 2.12 & 1.37 & 0.75 & 2.23 & 1.47 & 0.70 & 2.36 & 1.75 & 0.40 & 3.39 & 1.59 & 0.30 \\ 
15 & 1.10 & 1.03 & 0.78 & 2.13 & 1.46 & 0.78 & 2.27 & 1.30 & 0.73 & 2.50 & 1.59 & 0.43 & 3.54 & 1.89 & 0.53 \\ 
16 & 1.18 & 1.05 & 0.79 & 2.00 & 1.39 & 0.70 & 2.13 & 1.35 & 0.78 & 2.58 & 1.67 & 0.58 & 3.23 & 1.88 & 0.48 \\ 
17 & 1.19 & 1.08 & 0.80 & 2.13 & 1.48 & 0.60 & 2.35 & 1.55 & 0.65 & 2.56 & 1.70 & 0.55 & 3.28 & 1.79 & 0.5 \\ 
18 & 1.21 & 1.09 & 0.85 & 2.19 & 1.29 & 0.85 & 2.10 & 1.36 & 0.64 & 2.65 & 1.72 & 0.54 & 3.92 & 1.85 & 0.44 \\ 
19 & 1.25 & 1.12 & 0.90 & 2.16 & 1.36 & 0.50 & 2.14 & 1.55 & 0.59 & 2.54 & 1.58 & 0.59 & 3.53 & 1.75 & 0.44 \\ 
20 & 1.44 & 0.95 & 0.67 & 2.17 & 1.47 & 0.60 & 2.15 & 1.45 & 0.48 & 2.50 & 1.65 & 0.58 & 3.22 & 1.69 & 0.48 \\ 
21 & 1.39 & 0.90 & 0.71 & 2.34 & 1.51 & 0.58 & 2.19 & 1.54 & 0.58 & 2.59 & 1.72 & 0.48 & 3.27 & 1.88 & 0.38 \\ 
22 & 1.17 & 0.99 & 0.75 & 2.10 & 1.50 & 0.75 & 2.10 & 1.40 & 0.59 & 2.80 & 1.63 & 0.49 & 3.60 & 1.80 & 0.39 \\ 
23 & 1.15 & 1.01 & 0.86 & 2.30 & 1.45 & 0.64 & 2.13 & 1.34 & 0.39 & 2.75 & 1.65 & 0.59 & 3.23 & 1.71 & 0.49 \\
24 & 1.08 & 1.07 & 0.87 & 2.01 & 1.34 & 0.73 & 2.24 & 1.60 & 0.58 & 2.65 & 1.53 & 0.48 & 3.89 & 1.74 & 0.38 \\ 
26 & 1.05 & 1.05 & 0.90 & 2.00 & 1.56 & 0.09 & 2.26 & 1.61 & 0.49 & 2.85 & 1.59 & 0.59 & 3.65 & 1.63 & 0.49 \\ 
27 & 1.03 & 1.10 & 0.88 & 2.10 & 1.40 & 0.58 & 2.10 & 1.48 & 0.77 & 2.55 & 1.68 & 0.57 & 3.83 & 1.80 & 0.47 \\ 
28 & 1.25 & 1.11 & 0.76 & 2.09 & 1.35 & 0.56 & 2.15 & 1.50 & 0.58 & 2.60 & 1.75 & 0.48 & 3.35 & 1.79 & 0.38 \\
\midrule
{Avg.} & 1.12 & 2.23& 2.00& 2.50 & 3.4\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Load only the packages you need; for instance, `subfloat` and `subcaption` are meant to do similar things and you should only load one of them.

`\pagenumbering{gobble}` *seems* to work. If you don't want page numbers, issue `\pagestyle{empty}`.